# Not able to get/write values into text file from Installer Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, installation

I have a installer class in my winform application by using which i am creating setup of my application.Now i want the values entered into setup textboxes to get retrieved into installer class and write into text file using custom action .Here is the parameter i am trying to send using custom action of Setup project..

```
/targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"/Param1="[EDITA1]"/Param2="[EDITA2]"/Param3="[EDITA3]"
```

And here is the way i am trying to retrieve and write into newly created text file which is not happening..

```
 public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {

        base.Install(stateSaver);

        string targetDirectory = Context.Parameters["targetdir"];

        string param1 = Context.Parameters["Param1"];

        string param2 = Context.Parameters["Param2"];

        string param3 = Context.Parameters["Param3"];

        try
        {
            File.Create("D:\\Yourfile.txt");
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("D:\\Yourfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
            writer.Write("Hello", writer.NewLine);
            writer.Write(param1, writer.NewLine);
            writer.Write(param2, writer.NewLine);
            writer.Write(param3, writer.NewLine);
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch { 

        }
      }
```

I am not able to get even `Hello` in my textfile.Please tell me where i am going wrong..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a file and then trying to access it , which generates an `IOException`, which you happily swallow with the empty catch.

You can simply comment out the following line  `File.Create("D:\\Yourfile.txt");`, and then it'll work for you.

Do note that you're writting lines, and relaying on the `writer.NewLine`. I would probably use the following if this is what you want:

```
writer.WriteLine("hello");
```

Other than that, You can also just write to a string or an array of strings, and do :

```
var first_ten = read_all_lines.Take(10);
var out_path =  "D:\\Yourfile.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(out_path, first_ten);
```